# What type of Schema would be used in a documentation type page

Tags: schema.org

For example, what type of Schema would something like [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/) use?

The most relevant seems to be [TechArticle](https://schema.org/TechArticle) but the actual usage of that type is very low (between 100 and 1000 domains).

Comment: [Software](https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication), [CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) or [SoftwareSourceCode](https://schema.org/SoftwareSourceCode) would work but there are others you can use too. Schema uses broad categories so your find in most niches there are many sub categories that match, don't worry to much about this, Google and other search engines still use their algorithms to establish what the page is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Schema.org’s nine sub-types of [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing), it becomes clear that documentation would have to be a type that inherits from [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork).

In the next level, [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) seems to be the most appropriate.

And from the sub-types of `Article`, the type [**`TechArticle`**](http://schema.org/TechArticle) seems to be suitable:

> A technical article - Example: How-to (task) topics, step-by-step, procedural troubleshooting, specifications, etc.

It even has a sub-type for an API reference: [**`APIReference`**](http://schema.org/APIReference)

> Reference documentation for application programming interfaces (APIs).

---

For deciding which type to use, you should ignore the usage statistics. It’s irrelevant how often a type gets used in other documents if you need this type for your document. (*Oh, and someone has to start, right?*)

Besides that, the statistics include only a small subset of sites, and they get updated rarely.

And you’ll probably always find that the usage stats for types that are not connected with search engine features (like Rich Snippets) will be comparatively low.

Answer (score 1):

You should use TechArticle schema, because it is most related to your framework website.

Don't count usage, because most of CMS like WordPress have plugin for news article, and Blogger.com by default using BlogPosting schema, and hence their usage are high.

As per my experience, I have seen only [News Rich snippet in Search Result](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles). All other schema like TechArticle, BlogPosting, ArticleBody did not display rich snippet in SERP, except the date(Time), that you want to display in search result.