# Schema.org type for image galleries on a page

Tags: images, schema.org, photo-gallery

I have articles on my site that can contain one or more photo galleries that are related to the article's content. The [schema.org/ImageGallery](http://schema.org/ImageGallery) is defined as a "Web page type: Image gallery page" and as such inherits from the [schema.org/WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) type.  The gallery opens up in a lightbox without changing pages though.

Is there a more appropriate type for a gallery that is just a feature *on* a page, related to the larger containing article?

I have seen the [bib Collection type](http://schema.org/Collection) but it's low usage (Usage: Between 10 and 100 domains) and fact that it's not in core makes me concerned.

---

I've seen this [related question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91259/schema-for-image-gallery-photo) but their question is more about the images.

Comment: I wonder if just adding the ImageType for each image can be correct. This way you can have a WebPage (your article) with a list of images (the gallery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I agree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284437/1591669) that [`ImageGallery`](http://schema.org/ImageGallery) is not a suitable type for your case.

There are two alternatives to `Collection`, but they have drawbacks, so I think `Collection` is the best solution here.

#### `hasPart`

The most simple solution would be to use multiple values for the [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
  <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
  <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
</article>
```

Problem: It doesn’t allow you to group the images into sets. So if it’s important for you to convey which gallery the images belong to (in case an article has multiple galleries), this doesn’t work.

#### `ItemList`

The [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) type can be used to group the images (where each gallery is represented by a list).

Problem: You can’t connect the `ItemList`s to the `Article`, because the [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property expects a `CreativeWork` as value, but `ItemList` isn’t one.

(One case where it does work is if the galleries are the primary items described in the article. In that case, you could use the [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) property to connect the `ItemList`s to the `Article`.)

#### `Collection`

[`Collection`](http://bib.schema.org/Collection) is a `CreativeWork`, so `hasPart` can be used:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Collection">
    <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
    <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
    <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Collection">
    <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
    <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
  </div>
</article>
```

(If needed, you could of course also combine this with `ItemList`.)

There is no need to be concerned:

- For deciding which type to use, [ignore the usage statistics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/88768/17633).
- It’s no problem that a type is part of an extension. It’s just an organizational decision. Everything in an extension is still part of the main namespace (i.e., you can/should use `http://schema.org/Collection` instead of `http://bib.schema.org/Collection`).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I will look at articles with more than one gallery to decide if the simple hasPart solution works well enough for my needs, but may end up using Collection at the end of the day because there may be situations in the future where galleries show up on types other than  articles.

Comment: One more clarifying comment: These galleries are in the middle of the Article.articleBody which is of a type text, so it'd probably be invalid to do this with microdata. I'd have to use JSON+LD to have it properly/validly related to the article.

Comment: @tenor528: Should be fine to use it in Microdata. The `text` (btw., you may want to use [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody)) property takes the *textContent* as value, it [ignores any markup](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90696/17633) (including Microdata) in that content.